# PuLP Optimization problem - how to add constraints?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, pulp

I am trying to solve a linear programming problem with the following constraints: [image]
for some given values of `N` and `T`. So suppose `N={1,2}` and `T={1,2}`
It is easy to write out for small |N|, but is impossible to write as N becomes large.

Im confused as to how to actually code these sums by indexing on my objective variables.

I used the following to create my objective variables:

```
for t in range(1,T+1):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        for j in range(1,n+1):
            # Skip the x_i,i,t entries
            if j == i:
                continue
            element = "x"+str(i)+','+str(j)+','+str(t)
            x_ijt_holding.append(element)
            
x_ijt =[]
for i in x_ijt_holding:
    x_ijt.append(pulp.LpVariable(i, cat = "Binary"))
```

Initially I thought I could just define each constraint with LpVariable, but I realized the solver doesn't like that.

For example I did:

```
# Constraint 2 enter entries
x_ijt_2_holding = []
for j in range(1,n+1):
    for i in range(1,j):
        equations_2 = []
        equations_3 = []
        for t in range(1, T+1):
            equations_2.append("x"+str(i)+','+str(j)+','+str(t))
            equations_2.append("x"+str(j)+','+str(i)+','+str(t))
        x_ijt_2_holding.append(equations_2)
        
# Constraint 2 as LpVariable:
for i in x_ijt_2_holding:
    temp = []
    for sublist in i:
        temp.append(pulp.LpVariable(sublist, cat = "Binary"))
x_ijt_con2.append(temp)
```

So how would I then code the constraints into the problem?

Comment: This is kind of a mess.  You only appear to have one variable, `x[i,j,t]`.  Where are you defining that, and how?  You should be using `LpVariable.dicts()` to do it.  can you edit your code to include that.  You should not need to add any variables to deal with constraints...but we can get to that.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing in the end. It made my issue a little simpler.

Comment: OK.  So did you get the constraints figured out?  If not, you should edit your post above to show how you are defining your variable, `x` and what attempt you have made at the constraints.  It should just be a couple of loops, `LpSum()`s, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constraints defines relationships on previously defined variable written as equations.  When you are building your constraints you need to reference the variables you defined in your first part.  Saving your variables in dicts makes it much easier to reference your variables later.

Take a look at this

```
"""
Optimizing

sum(x[i][j][t] + x[j][i][t]) ==1 where j in N \ {i} for each i in N and for each t in T
sum(x[i][j][t] + x[j][i][t]) ==2 where t in T for each i,j in N, i < j

programmer Michael Gibbs
"""

import pulp

N = [1,2]
T = [1,2]

model = pulp.LpProblem("basis")

# variables
# x[i][j][t]
x = {
    i:{
        j:{
            t:pulp.LpVariable(
                'x_' + str(i) + '_' + str(j) + '_' + str(t),
                cat=pulp.LpBinary
            )
            for t in T
        }
        for j in N if j != i
    }
    for i in N
}

# constraints
#sum(x[i][j][t] + x[j][i][t]) ==1 where j in N \ {i} for each i in N and for each t in T
for i in N:
    for t in T:
        c = pulp.lpSum([x[i][j][t] + x[j][i][t] for j in N if j != i]) == 1
        model += c

#sum(x[i][j][t] + x[j][i][t]) ==2 where t in T for each i,j in N, i < j
for i in N:
    for j in N:
        if i < j:
            c = pulp.lpSum([x[i][j][t] + x[j][i][t] for t in T]) == 2
            model += c

# no objective

model.solve()

print("i","j","t","value")
print('-------------------')
[print(i,j,t, pulp.value(x[i][j][t])) for i in N for j in N if i != j for t in T]
```